# Remove multiple object from object using 2 parameter filter (Angular)

Tags: angular, filter

How can I remove objects from an array by filtering based on multiple values?

Below is my code:

```
removeArray.filter(function(ra) {
    fullArray.controls = fullArray.controls.filter(function(sa) {
        return sa.value.name!== ra.value.name && sa.value.product !== ra.value.product;
    });
  });
```

The problem is this line:

```
sa.value.name!== ra.value.name && sa.value.product !== ra.value.product
```

This seems to remove objects that either have a name or product match, rather than have both name AND product match (i.e., !== seems to make the && work as an ||)

I would like it to remove only objects where both name && product match

Comment: what is your expectation?

Comment: I want it to remove objects where name && product match.  I.e., same as filter would do if I used === instead of !==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!(sa.value.name=== ra.value.name && sa.value.product === ra.value.product)
```

or

```
sa.value.name !== ra.value.name || sa.value.product !== ra.value.product
```

also change the functions to arrow function

```
removeArray.filter((ra) => {
    fullArray.controls = fullArray.controls.filter((sa) =>
          sa.value.name!== ra.value.name || sa.value.product !== ra.value.product
    );
  });
```

as a note the code is smelly, since you set fullArray.controls over and over so seems that the whole code is not correct